# Spark Connect Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, spark-connect

[Spark Connect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html) has been released as of Spark 3.4.

Does anyone know how to deploy spark-connect enabled spark cluster to Kubernetes? It would be best if it is deployed using Helm.